# Paging Library Filter/Search PageList<T>

Tags: android, search, android-jetpack, android-paging

I am using the Android Paging Library like described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html

But i also have an EditText for searching Countries by Name.

How can i filter the results from the Paging library to display only matching Countries ?

public final LiveData> countriesPagedList;

```
public AllCountriesViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    appRepository = new AppRepository(application);


PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .setPageSize(30)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
        .setPrefetchDistance(50)
        .build();

    countriesPagedList = new LivePagedListBuilder(appRepository.getAllCountries(),config).build();
}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: cant share the code

Comment: instead of `appRepository.getAllCountries()` you would need `appRepository.getFilteredCountries(filter)` - where `getFilteredCountries` would return only those countries that match `filter` String

Comment: how would i get filter data/string in this class?
how to write a match qurey in room?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have reasonable understanding of paging library, room and rx, several things need to be done:

1. Say you store your paged entities like this: `private final LiveData<PagedList<YourEntity>> yourEntities;`
2. Here is something to store your filter text: `private final MutableLiveData<String> filterText = new MutableLiveData<>();`
3. Here is how you bind them together:

   ```
   this.yourEntities = Transformations.switchMap(
           filterText, (Function<String, LiveData<PagedList<YourEntity>>>) input -> {
               if (StringUtils.isBlank(input)) {
                   return new LivePagedListBuilder(
                           yourEntitiesManagementDao.queryYourEntities(), PAGE_SIZE).build();
               } else {
                   return new LivePagedListBuilder(
                           yourEntitiesManagementDao.queryYourEntitiesFiltered("%" + input + "%"), PAGE_SIZE).build();
               }
           }
   );
   ```
4. Make sure you init filter text, like so for example `this.filterText.setValue("");`
5. Last but not least, you will also need `public void setFilter(String filter) {
       filterText.setValue(filter);
   }`

Basically, with the above setup you just need to `setFilter` with text from your EditText.

Comment: I don't think this strictly answered the question because I guess it asked how to filter the already acquired list (ok, it's not the most specific/clear question), but you totally pushed me in the right direction, so +1, thx

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `SQL query` to *fetch the results* according to country name in your `Dao`

```
@Dao
class YourDao {
  @Query("Select * FROM countryEntity WHERE countryName LIKE :countryName")
  fun getCountryNameFilter(countryName : String) : MutableList<Country>
}
```